# Tengo problemas al generar un Reporte en equipos clientes aplicacion VB.net y SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reportviewer

Buenas tardes recurro a uds. para que me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema.

Tengo una tabla que se llama ASISTENCIA, dentro de una Base de datos BDASISTENCIA en SQL Server

Como pudo hacer para primero al cargar el formulario carguen todos los datos en el ReportViewer y por otro lado quiero agregarle un filtro de hora, por decir que me filtre quienes llegaron después de las 8:00

La tabla Asistencia contiene las siguientes columnas: id, Apynombres, DNI, horaingreso, horasalida

He intentado hacerlo editando consultas con el dataset, pero funciona bien solo en el equipo servidor y los otros equipos me sale que no se pudo conectar con el servidor.

Gracias de antemano

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Public Class frmgradoyseccion

    Public cm As SqlConnection
    Public CadenaConexion As String
    Private Sub frmgradoyseccion_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'AsistenciaDataSet.ASISTENCIA' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
        Me.ASISTENCIATableAdapter.Fill(Me.AsistenciaDataSet.ASISTENCIA)

        Dim CadenaConexion As String
        Try
            cm = New SqlConnection
            CadenaConexion = ("Data Source=EDUSERVER2; initial catalog=Asistencia; user id=Ricardo;password=Nevermind44.;")
            cm.ConnectionString = CadenaConexion
            cm.Open()
            Mostrar()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("No se puedo conectar a la base de datos")
        End Try

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport
    End Sub
    Private Sub Mostrar()
        ''CADENA MOSTAR base de DATOS
        Dim oda As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ods As New DataSet
        Dim consulta As String
        consulta = "select *FROM ASISTENCIA"
        oda = New SqlDataAdapter(consulta, cm)
        ods.Tables.Add("ASISTENCIA")
        oda.Fill(ods.Tables("ASISTENCIA"))
        ASISTENCIADataGridView.DataSource = ods.Tables("ASISTENCIA")
    End Sub
```

Por otra parte la carga de datos al informe la hago desde un dataset 
[image: Error al generar reporte en PC Cliente]

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra explica la razón de la falla. No es posible conectarse al servidor de bases de datos.

En tu caso específico puede ser por las siguientes razones:

- Dices que en el servidor funciona: Puede que **EDUSERVER2** esté registrado en el archivo **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** en el servidor y este resuelva a una dirección IP específica. Puede que tu pc no tenga registrada esta entrada. *Es importante realizar un respaldo del archivo hosts en caso que tengas que modificarlo*.
- Si no estás conectado a la red de tu empresa, es probable que necesites una VPN para que tus peticiones puedan llegar al servidor.

El error que obtienes puede tener una multitud de causas. Espero esto te apunte en la dirección correcta.

Comment: Resolví el problema cambiando el nombre del Servidor por la IP. y colocando dentro de la conexión trustcerticate =true

Comment: Genial. En otros escenarios, puedes agregar la entrada al archivo de hosts. Así, si hay otros proyectos que también utilicen el nombre, no será necesario reemplazarlos por la ip.